# Why are we setting factory as null?

Tags: java, android, sql, inheritance, android-sqlite

So, what's the point behind this code? (I am new to SQL in Android) I made a new class to make a database through SQLiteOpenHelper class. What context are we talking about here? And Why are we passing 'null' for factory? Can anyone explain the thorough working of code in detail? Thanks.

The super syntax is: `super(Context,databaseName,factory,databaseVersion)`

```
public class DBOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "database.db";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

public DBOpenHelper(Context context) {
    super(context,DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}
```

Comment: What does the documentation of the constructor tell you about that factory parameter? http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/

Comment: Probably because its not needed in the code.

Comment: I'd recommend looking at the [javadoc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#SQLiteOpenHelper(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String,%20android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory,%20int)), and exploring the source code in your IDE

Answer (score 0):

> So, what's the point behind this code?

[SQLiteOpenHelper](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper) is a helper class, that is, it is abstract and therefore it requires a subclass (i.e. it must be extended and cannot be used on it's own). Additionally it requires that the **onCreate** and **onUpgrade** methods are overridden by the subclass.

> What context are we talking about here?

It needs a **Context** so as to be able to determine/extract the **package name**, which is used to determine where the database file will be located. Context itself provides Application Environment Information (which includes the package).
[Context](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context)

> And Why are we passing 'null' for factory?

**factory**, if not null, is a [CursorFactory](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory.html) that allows handling (overriding methods) by way of a [SQLiteCursorDriver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteCursorDriver.html) Cursor events. Seldom are such overrides needed and hence **null** is typically used, as it indicates that no factory is to be used.

So to be correct your code, at a minimum should be :-

```
public class DBOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "database.db";

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    public DBOpenHelper(Context context) {
        super(context,DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    }
}
```

- If the above were run, the resultant database would be empty from your perspective as no tables have been defined. 2 Tables would actually exist

  - the SQLite table **sqlite_master** that is the schema of the database
  - and specifically for **Android** the table called **android_metadata** which contains the **[locale](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale)**
- The **onCreate** method automatically runs just once for the lifetime of the database, that is for it to run the database file must not exist. The database file name will be exactly the same name as the database name (i.e. it is the file name). It will be located at /data/data/the_package_name/databases/ (hence the need for the Context as the_package_name will be dependent upon the package name).
- The **onUpgrade** method will run if the 4th parameter (database version), is greater than the version number that is stored by the SQLiteOpenHelper in the database (it uses the SQLite user_version field, that is part of the [Database Header](https://www.sqlite.org/fileformat2.html#database_header)).
- **WARNING** should the provided database version be lower than in the database unless the **onDowngrade** method is overwritten the App will crash.
- There may also be other files as per [Temporary Files Used By SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/tempfiles.html), -journal (up to Android Pie) OR -wal and -shm (from Android Pie) will often be seen. From Android Pie the default has been changed from **journal** to **wal** (write-ahead logging).

> So, what's the point behind this code? (part 2/extra)

You are not restricted to using the SQLiteOpenHelper. You can open (connect) an SQLiteDatabase using the [SQliteDatabase openDatabase](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#openDatabase(java.lang.String,%20android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory,%20int)) or the [SQLiteDatabase openOrCreateDatabase](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#openOrCreateDatabase(java.io.File,%20android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory)) methods.

Comment: MikeT, can you give some insight as to why OnDowngrade exists?  I've never released a new version of a product where the database version decreases.  If there was an "undoing" to be done, it would be done as an upgrade to a higher version number.  I'm considering throwing an exception if OnDowngrade is called, as I don't see why I would need it.

Comment: @MarkLongmire you might, as an interim measure need to backout a change, which is not the rarest of events. There is no need for you to throw an exception if onDownGrade is called. It already does that (hence the warning). *If not overridden, default implementation will reject downgrade and throws SQLiteException* [onDowngrade](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#onDowngrade(android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase,%2520int,%2520int))

Comment: Thanks @MikeT, I saw the docs on the default exception, just after posting.